# doctrine2 save and restore data into entities graph

Tags: php, serialization, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm using symfony2 with doctrine 2.

I have developed a feature where the user import the data into the db from an external source. I now have to implement a "revert" functionality. Basically the user should be able to undo the entire import operation with one click.

The behaviour would be the same as a mysql rollback or a mysqldump + reimport for a subset of the data, but I need to work at the application level with Doctrine 2.

Serializing and unserializing the proxies or playing with Unit of work did both not work out.
I'm now implementing an utility class to save/restore a entity (and the specified relationships) to/from an array, but it's a lot of work to manage all the relationships.

Is there any simpler solution ?

Comment: I gave up the generic utility class, it was almost fully working except some small edge cases that made everything over-elaborate. For simplicity and time reasons, I've ended up implementing a custom data transformer from/to array that I could easily serialize

Answer (score 0):

I do not consider the following an elegant solution given that it is very intrusive, but it may help and is most likely quite efficient:

For each entity specify an *import* field which refers to an *Import* entity. When reverting just delete all of the entities which map to a given *Import*. If modifying the entities to add the *import* field is too intrusive or otherwise not an option one might consider a OneToOne relationship which maps an import to a specific entity. This reduces coupling somewhat, too.

If an import consists of updates, too, things will obviously become more complicated; the same goes for modifications that happen to the data after the import. The revert will either fail or cascade to new entities.